# Как прижать Элементы DIV-а к краю

Tags: javascript, html, css

Как прижать div и все его элементы к правому краю, и при скроле он шел за ним 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Где аттестация и кнопка назад, при скроле в право должен прижиматься к правому краю
[image: Где аттестация и кнопка назад, при скроле в право должен прижиматься к правому краю]

Comment: какие элементы? где? покажите пальцем. В идеале покажите то, как должно быть.

Comment: Вот где Аттестация написано должно при скроле в право всегда прижиматься к правому краю

Comment: приведите код страницы

Answer (score 1):

не совсем понятно " и при скроле он шел за ним" кто за кем?
вообще прижать блок можно флотом, float: right; а по сути не понял вопроса

Answer (score 0):

Все извиняюсь, просто сделал position fixed, right: 0;

Answer (score 0):

Оберни свою таблицу в див и включи скроллинг по X

```
<style>
  .table-zone{
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    overflow-x: auto;
  }
</style>

<div class="table-zone">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div><!-- /.table-zone -->
```